# window.requestFileSystem is undefined in ver 3.3.0

Tags: javascript, ios, apache, cordova

I've been using Cordova (with iOS) on an app I've been developing for some time now. I've been able to access filesystem just fine in the past.

I installed cordova 3.3.0 with Node via the Command Line Interface and added all the plugins I needed (pretty much all of the plugins- including file of course)

When I list the plugins, I get:
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:hello michael$ cordova plugin ls

```
[ 'org.apache.cordova.battery-status',
'org.apache.cordova.console',
'org.apache.cordova.device-motion',
'org.apache.cordova.device-orientation',
'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
'org.apache.cordova.file',
etc....']
```

However, I try to run the following test code: note that the code is inside the index.js file, which is correctly referenced in index.html

**Index.html references:**

```
 script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"
 script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"
```

**index.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("ready");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   alert("got fs");
   alert(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
}
```

All I get is "ready"
If I try to alert(window.requestFileSystem); I get undefined.

Please would someone, help me sort this out? I see no reason why it shouldn't be working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Michael Mac Donald

Answer (score 1):

Have you added file-transfer plugin?

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your app in chrome you might have to run this the first time to reserve some space on the file system:

```
// Request Quota (only for File System API)  
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
}, function(e) {
  console.log('Error', e); 
});
```

More info at https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage

I'm not sure this solution fits your case as you said your app worked in the past, but give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I'm not testing my app in Chrome though. I'm using xcode with the built in iOS simulator